# how to remove step attribute of number field from webform component in drupal 7

Tags: php, html, drupal, html-input, drupal-webform

I have designed one Drupal 7 webform having fields (user name, Phone Number, email id).
Please see the source bellow:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYHRX.png)

The phone Number field having **step** attribute which is giving error in accessibility. I want to remove this for the accessibility compliance. What should I do for this?

Comment: I think you have to use form alter to remove the step attribute

Comment: Please can you share any example for this.Please

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with form alter :

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'your_form_id') {
    $fieldname = 'my_field_name_to_edit';
    if(isset($form[$fieldname]['#attributes']['step'])) unset($form[$fieldname]['#attributes']['step']);
  }
}
```

Find documentation here : https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x

And

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7.x#attributes

Answer (score 0):

For Webfor Number fields the step attribute is forcibly added in [`theme_webform_number()`](https://www.rit.edu/drupal/api/drupal/sites%21all%21modules%21webform%21components%21number.inc/function/theme_webform_number/7.54), so the only way would be to override that function in your theme and remove that bit of code:

```
/**
 * Theme function to render a number component.
 */
function YOURTHEME_webform_number($variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];

  // This IF statement is mostly in place to allow our tests to set type="text"
  // because SimpleTest does not support type="number".
  if (!isset($element['#attributes']['type'])) {
    // HTML5 number fields are no long used pending better browser support.
    // See issues #2290029, #2202905.
    // $element['#attributes']['type'] = 'number';
    $element['#attributes']['type'] = 'text';
  }

  // Step property *must* be a full number with 0 prefix if a decimal.
  if (!empty($element['#step']) && !is_int($element['#step'] * 1)) {
    $decimals = strlen($element['#step']) - strrpos($element['#step'], '.') - 1;
    $element['#step'] = sprintf('%1.' . $decimals . 'F', $element['#step']);
  }

  // If the number is not an integer and step is undefined/empty, set the "any"
  // value to allow any decimal.
  if (empty($element['#integer']) && empty($element['#step'])) {
    $element['#step'] = 'any';
  }
  elseif ($element['#integer'] && empty($element['#step'])) {
    $element['#step'] = 1;
  }
  unset($element['#step']);

  // Convert properties to attributes on the element if set.
  // removed step attribute.
  foreach (array('id', 'name', 'value', 'size', 'min', 'max') as $property) {
    if (isset($element['#' . $property]) && $element['#' . $property] !== '') {
      $element['#attributes'][$property] = $element['#' . $property];
    }
  }
  _form_set_class($element, array('form-text', 'form-number'));

  return '<input' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . ' />';
}
```

Hope this helps you...